# Trying to find the numbers which could be shown in 3 different ways using Legendre's three-square theorem

Tags: equation-solving, programming, number-theory

Legendre's three-square theorem states that

$n=a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$

if and only if $n$ is not of the form $n = 4^a(8b + 7)$ for integers $a$ and $b$.

There are numbers like 54 which can be represented as the sum of three perfect squares in two different ways:

$1^2+2^2+7^2\\
3^2+3^2+6^2$

I would really appreciate if someone could guide me through the code so that I could find the next number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[n_] := Block[{sol}, 
  sol = FindInstance[
    n == a^2 + b^2 + c^2 && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0, {a, b, c}, 
    Integers, 10];
  If[sol == {}, {}, 
   If[Length@DeleteDuplicates@(Sort /@ ({a, b, c} /. sol)) < 3, {}, 
    DeleteDuplicates@(Sort /@ ({a, b, c} /. sol))]]]

i = 167;
While[f[i] == {}, i++]
i
f[i]
```

> 171
>
> {{3, 9, 9}, {1, 7, 11}, {1, 1, 13}, {5, 5, 11}}

---

```
t = Join[##] & @@@ 
  Select[Table[{{i}, f[i]}, {i, 167, 300}] /. {{} -> Nothing[]}, 
   Length@# > 1 &];

TableForm[t, TableDepth -> 2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`IntegerPartitions` works well for numbers of reasonable size, where "reasonable" depends on your computing resources.

```
SumOfThreeSquares[n_Integer] := 
   Sqrt[IntegerPartitions[n, {3}, Range[Sqrt[n]]^2]]

SetAttributes[SumOfThreeSquares, Listable]
```

As in:

```
SumOfThreeSquares[166]
(* {{11, 6, 3}, {9, 9, 2}, {9, 7, 6}} *)
```

Find numbers up to 200 which are the sum of three squares in exactly three different ways:

```
With[{n = Range[200]},
   Pick[n, Map[Length, SumOfThreeSquares[n]], 3]]

(* {54, 66, 81, 86, 89, 99, 101, 110, 114, 126, 131, 149, 150, 162, 166,
    173, 174, 179, 182, 185, 186} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a brute force method that generates all distinct 3-tuples up to some aMax, groups them into an association based on the value a^2+b^2+c^2 and selects those keys with three or more tuples matching the requirement:

```
aMax=12;
distinctTuples=DeleteDuplicates[Sort/@Tuples[Range[aMax],3]];
groupedTuples=GroupBy[distinctTuples,Total[#^2]&];
ans=Select[groupedTuples,Length[#]>=3&];

TableForm@Normal@KeySort@ans
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way to pick out integers that are the sum of exactly three squares:

```
Select[Table[{k, Select[PowersRepresentations[k, 3, 2], FreeQ[#, 0] &]},
             {k, 101, 200}], Length[Last[#]] == 3 &]
   {{101, {{1, 6, 8}, {2, 4, 9}, {4, 6, 7}}}, {110, {{1, 3, 10}, {2, 5, 9}, {5, 6, 7}}},
    {114, {{1, 7, 8}, {4, 7, 7}, {5, 5, 8}}}, {126, {{1, 2, 11}, {1, 5, 10}, {3, 6, 9}}},
    {131, {{1, 3, 11}, {1, 7, 9}, {5, 5, 9}}}, {149, {{1, 2, 12}, {2, 8, 9}, {6, 7, 8}}},
    {150, {{1, 7, 10}, {2, 5, 11}, {5, 5, 10}}},
    {162, {{3, 3, 12}, {4, 5, 11}, {7, 7, 8}}},
    {166, {{2, 9, 9}, {3, 6, 11}, {6, 7, 9}}},
    {173, {{2, 5, 12}, {3, 8, 10}, {4, 6, 11}}},
    {174, {{1, 2, 13}, {2, 7, 11}, {5, 7, 10}}},
    {179, {{1, 3, 13}, {3, 7, 11}, {7, 7, 9}}},
    {182, {{1, 9, 10}, {2, 3, 13}, {5, 6, 11}}},
    {185, {{2, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 12}, {6, 7, 10}}},
    {186, {{1, 4, 13}, {1, 8, 11}, {4, 7, 11}}}}
```